# How to show warnings "AdviceDidNotMatch" in eclipse/STS as errors?

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

We use some Apsects in our software. When we refactor a method, the pointcut doesn't match anymore. The advice gets a warning marker in eclipse. I want this advice to get an error marker instead of just a warning. I checked all preferences but it seems to be not possible to me.

Do you know how to show warnings "AdviceDidNotMatch" in eclipse/STS as errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a missing feature in AJDT. The message is an XLint so should be configurable. I just raised https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=444546 and committed a fix, so if you wait for a dev build tomorrow of AJDT (for eclipse 4.4) you will be able to set it. The update site for the new build will be: `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update`

To configure it:

Select project > right click > 'Properties' > Select 'AspectJ Compiler' on the left. In the right hand tab under the 'AspectJ 5' section you will see 'Advice did not match' which should default to 'warning'. Change it to 'error' and after a full build you will have your errors.

Comment: WOW! You are pretty cool and I would give millions of up votes if I could.